# Cypher / neo4j: sum by value and generate grand total

Tags: neo4j, cypher

here's my sample DB: http://console.neo4j.org/r/plb1ez

It contains 2 categories with the name "Digital Cameras" with this query, I group them by name and return significance*view_count for each of the category names:
`MATCH a

    WHERE a.metatype = "Category"

    RETURN DISTINCT a.categoryName, SUM(a.significance * a.view_count) AS popularity`

However, what I actually need is not the absolute popularity (=significance*view_count), but the relative one - so I need my query to additionally return the sum of all popularities (should be 1500 according to my math), so I can calculate the fraction (which I call "relativePopularity") for each category (popularity/grandTotal).

Desired result:

`|    d.categoryName    | popularity | grandTotal | relativePopularity |

| Digital Compacts     |        300 |       1500 | 0.2                |

| Hand-held Camcorders |        300 |       1500 | 0.2                |

| Digital SLR          |        150 |       1500 | 0.1                |

| Digital Cameras      |        750 |       1500 | 0.5                |

+----------------------+------------+------------+--------------------+`

Currently I'm doing this calculation with two ansynchronous jobs, but I need it done in one go.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay, one part I was able to fix myself: I now have the aggregation for each individual category, but not yet for all categories altogether.

Comment: MATCH p=a-[r]->(d:Category)
WHERE id(a)=34
WITH a,r,d, sum(distinct d.significance) as categorySum
RETURN id(a), d.categoryName, sum(categorySum) as categoryTotal
ORDER BY categoryTotal DESC
LIMIT 5

Comment: can you edit your post to reflect the solution?

Comment: I found a solution, which does the trick, but I doubt it's highly performant.
`
    MATCH (a:Category) WHERE a.view_count > 0
    WITH sum(a.view_count) AS total_views
    OPTIONAL MATCH (b:Category) WHERE b.view_count > 0
    WITH DISTINCT b.categoryId AS categoryId, sum(b.view_count) AS category_views, total_views
    OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Category) WHERE c.categoryId = categoryId
`